# 3D sphere mesh with a predefined number of vertices and a given adjacency matrix of vertices

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, mesh

I need a 3D triangular sphere mesh with uniformly sampled vertices, say $V$, with a predefined adjacency. Is there a specific way to achieve that?

Comment: One way to generate a triangulated sphere is to use an isosphere: https://schneide.wordpress.com/2016/07/15/generating-an-icosphere-in-c/

What do you mean by pre-defined adjacency? What's the purpose?

Comment: I need a 3D sphere consistent with a given 3D mesh in terms of the number of vertices and face-connectivity. The given mesh is genus 1, so I guess that is possible. I have looked into icosahedron division method but the issue is face-connectivity.